# GitLab CI only running one job and not other job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration where I want the job `update-environment` only to run on a push to main or on a MR to main.

Debugging the gitlab environment variables via `printenv` I can see that both rules defined should evaluate to `true`. But the job never runs. Does the job need to be defined in a stage or am I missing something?

```yaml
default:
  image: alpine
  tags:
    - "workstation"

validation:
  script:
    - |
      echo "I will always run"
      printenv # Checking GitLab Environment Variables

update-environment:
  rules:
    # - changes:
    #   - "*.yaml"
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"'
  script:
    - |
      echo "Updating environment"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with this

```yaml
stages:
  - check
  - main

validation:
  stage: check
  script:
    - |
      echo "I will always run"
      printenv # Checking GitLab Environment Variables

update-environment:
  stage: main
  rules:
    # - changes:
    #   - "*.yaml"
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
  script:
    - |
      echo "Updating environment"
```

I just added stages and removed quotes from CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH which you had added in the rules

Comment: Tested this out with pushing directly to main and then creating an MR against Main. Worked like a charm. Darn quotes...

Comment: Ya i have had similar experiences :)